# maven - Spring Boot/Angular 2/4 project war build

Tags: angular, maven, spring-boot, war

I have a Spring Boot and Angular 2/4 project that I want to package into a single WAR and serve on Tomcat. I have a parent project with 2 modules (1 for Angular and 1 for Spring Boot), with the following pom.xml configurations:

parent/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mk.edu.ukim.feit.bolt</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
</modules>
```

frontend/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>frontend</artifactId>


<name>Bolt Client</name>
<description>Bolt messaging app frontend client</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>mk.edu.ukim.feit.bolt</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>

            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v7.9.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>4.6.1</npmVersion>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm run prod</id>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run prod</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/frontend</directory>
            <targetPath>static</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

api/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Bolt API</name>
<description>Bolt messaging app REST API</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>mk.edu.ukim.feit.bolt</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mk.edu.ukim.feit.bolt</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I was following [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/) tutorial and I ended up successfully building the project running mvn clean install from the parent directory, then going into the api directory and running mvn spring-boot:run, the application is served on localhost:8080, however while building the war file Maven somehow doesn't pick up the static files compiled from Angular and gives me a 404 on http://localhost:8080. Could anyone give tips on what might be wrong here?

I also tried setting the "prod" NPM script to "ng build --prod --base-href=\"./\"" thinking it might have to do something with it but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found:

1. Copy a single "index.html" file to "src/main/resources/templates"
   folder under server project. Please note that HTML file structure must be very strict (all opened tags must be closed etc).
2. Add maven dependency "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
3. Create HomeController for request mapping "/" to "index" template

Sample:

```
@Controller
public class HomeContoller {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

See [GitHub commit with HomeController](https://github.com/makimenko/mem/commit/0eb4938cb51d27290b27dd0f66a4f5507984994e)
Would be great if someone know more cleaner/nicer solution and could share.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar layout where the angular app and webapp are in separate maven modules.  To bundle the angular app in the webapp I do the following:-

- Make the angular application files build in the **target/classes/static/frontend** directory.  I configure this using the **outputPath** parameter in the angular.json file in the **architect.build.options** section.  I also configure the **bashHref** and **deployUrl** settings here too.  Notice that the **architect.serve.options** are different so I can use ng serve for debugging and testing purposes.

  ```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "scrapit2myob-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "projects/scrapit2myob-frontend",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/scrapit2myob-frontend/src",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "target/classes/static/frontend",
            "index": "projects/scrapit2myob-frontend/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/scrapit2myob-frontend/src/main.ts",
            "baseHref": "/frontend/",
            "deployUrl": "/frontend/",
            ...
          },
          ...
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "scrapit2myob-frontend:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json",
            "baseHref": "/",
            "deployUrl": "/"
          },
          ...
  ```
- Let maven package the angular app as a jar file.  All the compiled angular files should appear in the static/frontend folder of that jar.
- Add the angular app jar file as a maven dependency of the web app project.  Since the angular files are in the static/frontend folder, they should be publicly accessible from the web application by default.
- In the webapp, I have a WebMvcConfigurer to configure redirects.  This is necessary if you have deep links in your angular frontend, if a user refreshes that link from the browser you need the server to serve index.html for those links.  The angular router then takes care of rendering the correct component...

  ```
    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/silent-refresh.html").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/receipts/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/tickets/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/supplier-mapping/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/item-mapping/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/account-mapping/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/job/**").setViewName("forward:/frontend/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
            registry.addViewController("/swagger-ui").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html");
            registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        }
    }
  ```
- The reason I use /static/frontend instead of just /static is so if you're securing your api, you can then configure urls matching /frontend to be ignored by the spring security filter...

  public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring.antMatchers("/frontend/**");
  }
  }